# Finding the critical points of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

What are the steps in finding the critical points of a function in general? Say for example, the function

$$f(x, y) = 2x^3 + 11x^2 + 0.5y^2 - 2xy$$

I can't quite seem to understand the steps/method involved.

Comment: It's the same as in Calc I. Take derivatives (now partials $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$) and figure out where both are zero.

Comment: why is this tagged as precalculus?

Answer (score 2):

$$\text{Partials:}\ f_x = 6x^2+22x-2y, f_y =y-2x. \text{You want that:} \ \  f_x=f_y=0$$
$$\text{Here} \ f_y = 0 \Rightarrow y = 2x \Rightarrow 6x^2+22x-2(2x) = 0 \Rightarrow 6x(x+3)=0 \Rightarrow x=0 \ \text{or} \ -3.$$